# Does pandas.DataFrame.drop(..., inplace=True) use extra memory?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, memory

Does [`drop()` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) make a copy of the data frame from which the values are dropped **while doing the dropping operation**? If so, is this true even if `inplace=True` is set? I don't see a reason why copying would be needed, but still want to make sure in order to optimize memory footprint of my code.

Answer (score 0):

that is really cool question, and let's consider some facts then.
First we'll create a dummy `DataFrame` object:

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

then lets read its parameters:

```
import sys
print(sys.getsizeof(df))
print(id(df))
>>320
>>4789316624
```

knowing those parameters lets read "dropped" object parameters:

```
print(sys.getsizeof(df.drop('A', axis=1)))
print(id(df.drop('A', axis=1)))
>>280
>>4793436944
```

and compare it with "dropped inplace" object:

```
df.drop('A', axis=1, inplace=True)
print(sys.getsizeof(df))
print(id(df))
>>280
>>4789316624
```

This proves sizes of object in both approaches decrease, but the memory address does not change in "inplaced" object, so there is extra memory in use.

Comment: I understand the steps you go through, but I do not understand why the memory address being the same for the inplaced object implies extra memory in use.